# Json-server command not found when executing Dockerfile

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile, json-server

Im trying to do a Dockerized Angular + Json-Server application but im having trouble setting json-server up, although I install it in the Dockerfile, using docker logs tells me that couldnt find the command json-server:

This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
    FROM node:18 as CervantesJuradoBuild
    
    ARG workdir="/home/CervantesJurado"
    
    WORKDIR /appContainer
    
    COPY /home/CervantesJurado/angular/A_Animals /appContainer
    
    RUN echo pwd
    
    WORKDIR /appContainer/A_Animals
    
    RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
    
    RUN npm cache clean --force
    
    RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    
    RUN npm run build
    
    FROM nginx as CervantesJuradoApp
    
    ENV name="CervantesJurado"
    
    LABEL author="$name"
    
    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y openssh-server nodejs npm
    
    RUN npm install -g json-server
    
    RUN mkdir -p /run/sshd
    
    RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    
    RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash $name && \
        mkdir -p /home/$name/.ssh && \
        chmod 700 /home/$name/.ssh
    
    COPY /home/CervantesJurado/angular/A_Animals/id_rsa.pub /home/$name/.ssh/authorized_keys
    
    COPY /home/CervantesJurado/angular/animals.json /home/$name/
    
    RUN chown -R $name:$name /home/$name/.ssh && \
        chmod 600 /home/$name/.ssh/authorized_keys
    
    USER root
    
    EXPOSE 22 80 3000
    
    CMD ["sh", "-c", "json-server --watch /home/$name/animals.json --host 0.0.0.0 & service ssh start && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
    
    COPY --from=CervantesJuradoBuild /appContainer/dist/a-animals /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And this is how i run it:

```bash
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -p 2222:22 -p 3000:3000 --name cervantes_container cervantesjurado:prueba3
```

After running the docker run command i use docker logs to see what happened:

> `docker logs cervantes_container`
>
> `sh: 1: json-server: not found`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run three separate processes in this container.  Can you run the `json-server`, the ssh daemon, and the Nginx server in three separate containers?  That would simplify the setup, it would let you use the unmodified `node` image as the base for `json-server`, and it would let you separately upgrade the three components and notice and restart if one of them failed.

Comment: Latest version is broken, workarounds on GitHub: https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1472.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected errors and warnings when running json-server --watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787616/unexpected-errors-and-warnings-when-running-json-server-watch)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came here as last resource and you are desperate, instead of using json-server use npm install json-server@v0.17.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `RUN npm i -g json-server@0.17.4` instead of `RUN npm install -g json-server` in Dockerfile.