# Unexpected errors and warnings when running json-server --watch

Tags: javascript, npm, json-server

I'm trying to use `json-server` as follows:

```bash
$ json-server --watch db.json
```

However, I'm getting errors or warnings when I run that command, depending on the version I have installed:

- `1.0.0-alpha.1`-`1.0.0-alpha.12`:

  ```
  sh: json-server: command not found
  ```

  or (on Windows):

  ```
  The term 'json-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  At line:1 char:1
  + json-server --watch db.json
  ```

  or (if executed via `npx`):

  ```
  npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
  ```
- `1.0.0-alpha.13`:

  ```
  node:internal/errors:496
      ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
      ^

  TypeError [ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION]: Unknown option '--watch'. To specify a positional argument starting with a '-', place it at the end of the command after '--', as in '-- "--watch"
  ```
- `1.0.0-alpha.14`+:

  ```
  --watch/-w can be omitted, JSON Server 1+ watches for file changes by default
  ```
- `1.0.0-alpha.13`+, if using Node.js before v18.3.0, v16.17.0:

  ```
  import { parseArgs } from 'node:util';
           ^^^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:util' does not provide an export named 'parseArgs'
  ```

Minimal package file (update version of `json-server` as needed):

```json
{
  "name": "q77787616",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "json-server --watch db.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "1.0.0-alpha.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`json-server` is currently in active development towards v1, but unfortunately these alpha versions are being published to npm with the `latest` tag, so are being installed in favour of the stable version (currently `0.17.4`) if you simply `npm install json-server`. This has caused various issues:

- Prior to `alpha.13` the correct binary wasn't installed at all, so the `json-server` command couldn't be found ([`typicode/json-server#1472`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1472)).
- With `alpha.13` the binary was included, but the CLI changed such that `--watch` was an invalid argument ([`typicode/json-server#1474`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1474)):

  ```bash
  $ npx json-server@1.0.0-alpha.13 --help
  Usage: json-server [options] <file>
  Options:
    -p, --port <port>  Port (default: 3000)
    -h, --host <host>  Host (default: localhost)
    -s, --static <dir> Static files directory (multiple allowed)
    --help  Show this message
  ```

  - The argument parsing is provided by [`parseArgs` from `node:util`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/util.html#utilparseargsconfig), which was introduced in Node.js v16.17 and v18.3, so earlier versions aren't supported.
- From `alpha.14` onwards, `--watch` is supported but unnecessary, so the message was reduced to a warning.

You can check which version you currently have installed with:

```
npm ls json-server
```

Given the active development and alpha status, the best thing to do currently is to explicitly install the stable version (the documentation for this is still available [here](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/tree/v0#readme)):

```bash
$ npm install json-server@0
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the alpha v1 and are using an appropriate Node.js version (i.e. `^16.17 || >=18.3`), you can `npm install json-server@latest` to get the latest version (ensure you have at least `alpha.14`) and use the command *without* the `--watch` flag:

```bash
$ json-server db.json
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:   Open "CMD"

Step 2:   `npm install -g json-server@0.17.4`

Step 3:   `json-server --watch db.json`

Sorce: https://github.com/typicode/json-server/tree/v0

Answer (score -2):

There’ll be no help updating json-server@0.17.4 in existing node_modules. Remove existing node_modules folder and install stable version json-server.

```
npm i json-server@0.17.4
```