# json-server in Angular project

Tags: angular, json-server

In my Angular project I hope to use `json-server`. After installation, use this code `json-server --watch db.json` to create `db.json` file, then give this error.

```
 file:///C:/Users/TIMON/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/json-server/lib/bin.js:4
import { parseArgs } from 'node:util';

SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:util' does not provide an export named 'parseArgs'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:127:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:191:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

I use Angular CLI 16.2.11, Node.js 16.14.0, npm 10.2.5, Windows x64.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected errors and warnings when running json-server --watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787616/unexpected-errors-and-warnings-when-running-json-server-watch)

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your Node.

The function `parseArgs` was added to `node:util` in v18.3.0, v16.17.0.

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilparseargsconfig)