# JSON-Server - sort returns empty array

Tags: json-server

I am running mock API on json-server and able to fetch data in URL with URL but when I pass `/products?_sort=price&_order=asc` I receive empty array.

I am able to fetch all products data through `localhost:8080/products` but when I add `_sort` and `_order` as per JSON server documents.

Not able to figure out the problem why it is returning empty array.

Json server docs
Sort :Add _sort and _order (ascending order by default)

`GET /posts?_sort=views&_order=asc`

Comment: Do your `product` entries have a `price` property?

Comment: Which version of json-server are you using? The v1-alpha doesn't appear to have an `_order` parameter

Comment: yeah product have price property and this this is the json-server version 1.0.0-alpha.21

Comment: Then try the stable version, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787616/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Server's behavior for sorting changed with different versions.

To resolve the issue, update JSON Server using the command:

***npm install -g json-server***

After updating, sorting by default will be ascending. No need to use _order:asc

**GET /products?_sort=price**

For descending order,

use ***GET /products?_sort=-price***

This will definitely help.

Best Of Luck ;)

Noor.

Comment: this works for json-server however for the server api testing I wanted to use query params but looks like json-server doesnt accept previous formate of _sort=price&_order=asc

Comment: Yeah, I think it's because of the different versions of json-server.