# json-server GET /posts?title_like=server not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-server

this is my json-object

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 10001,
      "name": "Basics To Advanced In React",
      "overview": "SOMETHING",
      "long_description": "SOMETHING",
      "rating": 5,
      "in_stock": true,
    },
    {
      "id": 10002,
      "name": "Django Framework for Beginners",
      "overview": "SOMETHING",
      "long_description": "SOMETHING",
      "rating": 5,
      "in_stock": false,
    },
  ],
}
```

other query's are working such as given below

```
http://localhost:8000/products [ works ]
http://localhost:8000/products?id=10001 [ works ]
```

but these 2 below are not working.

```
http://localhost:8000/products?name_like=react [ doesnt work ]
http://localhost:8000/products?in_stock=true [ doesnt work ]
```

this is the API call,

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProducts() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/products?name_like=${searchTerm}` // if searchTerm = react
      );

      const data = await response.json();
      setProducts(data);
    }
    fetchProducts();
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

consol.log(documents) - logs an empty array [] where as i should be getting this object when calling
http://localhost:8000/products?name_like=react

```
{
  "id": 10001,
  "name": "Basics To Advanced In React",
  "overview": "SOMETHING",
  "long_description": "SOMETHING",
  "rating": 5,
  "in_stock": true,
},
```

Comment: Which version of `json-server`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787616/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761 - it's iterating on an alpha right now.

Comment: "json-server": "^0.17.4",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest versions of json-server **doesn't** have *"_like"*.

You might have to *uninstall* json-server with

```
npm uninstall -g json-server
```

Then *install* the 0.17.4 version

```
npm i -g json-server@0.17.4
```

Comment: It's working with this json-server v0.17.4 that you provided. Thanks!

Comment: You [claimed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867124/json-server-get-poststitle-like-server-not-working#comment137276374_77867124) to be _already_ using that version...

Answer (score 0):

Just run in the same problem and randomly figured out that when you replace http://localhost:8000/products?in_stock=true with http://localhost:8000/products?in_stock=1 code works great!