# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'm', "module.exp"... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, json-server

```
$ npx json-server --version
1.0.0-alpha.23
$ node -v
v20.12.0
$ ls
generate.js  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  public  README.md  src
```

I am trying to run a React project on my local from GitHub repo. I have installed almost all dependencies, but having issues running a `.js` file with `json-server`.

The file I am trying to load via `json-server` is below:
https://github.com/brucevanhorn2/reactstrap-course/blob/master/generate.js

Here's the error I am getting in VS Code terminal after running the command:
`npx json-server  generate.js`

```
undefined:1
module.exports = function(){
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'm', "module.exp"... is not valid JSON
    at JSONFile.parse (<anonymous>)
    at JSONFile.read (file:///home/niveus/PRAKASH/VS_CODE/flying_cars/node_modules/lowdb/lib/adapters/node/DataFile.js:17:31)
    at async Observer.read (file:///home/niveus/PRAKASH/VS_CODE/flying_cars/node_modules/json-server/lib/observer.js:21:22)
    at async Low.read (file:///home/niveus/PRAKASH/VS_CODE/flying_cars/node_modules/lowdb/lib/core/Low.js:16:22)
    at async file:///home/niveus/PRAKASH/VS_CODE/flying_cars/node_modules/json-server/lib/bin.js:114:1

Node.js v20.12.0
```

I have tried different ways of export like
`export default () => {}`
in generate.js file, but still no luck.

What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: Yes. But as per the tutorial, once the course instructor runs the command 'npx json-server  generate.js', it shall generate API's like below -->
http://localhost:3000/vehicles
http://localhost:3000/dealerships
http://localhost:3000/mailingList

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, It's working fine after installing 'json-server@0'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like several other features, loading a JS file to [Generate random data](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/tree/v0?tab=readme-ov-file#generate-random-data) is not (or at least not *yet*) supported by `json-server@1`, the alpha release currently being published to npm as `latest`. This version *only* accepts a JSON file, hence the syntax errors on non-JSON content. So either:

- Use that file just to generate the JSON, then *save it as JSON* for use by `json-server`; or
- Install `json-server@0` to get the stable version (currently v0.17.4).

Related:

- [Unexpected errors and warnings when running json-server --watch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787616/3001761)
- [Using integers for IDs created "Not found" error in JSON server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761)

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, It's working fine after installing 'json-server@0'